# Python Pip vs Ruby Gems

Tags: python, ruby, rubygems, pip

I mostly do work in Python, but I have been using some of the Ruby stuff for Server Configuration Management (ie Puppet and Chef).  I also use Ubuntu/Debian as my primary Linux distro for servers.

Why is there a weird Debian/Ruby conflict over Gems, and not a similar showdown between Debian/Python over Pip?

Personally, I don't mind installing newer packages then the "system" approves of.  I know Debian wants to make a stable system, but when I am running my own application code on the server, I can guarantee you it's not stable to begin with.

Anyway, I would be interested to know if Pip is doing something different, or if it's an ego thing or whatever?

Comment: This is mostly a policy enforced by the debian people. Note that ruby will soon integrate bundler as-is so it should be simpler for users to install even larger projects. Debian may have another policy and enforce it rigidly - it is essentially treating external project managers as hostile to debian.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should raise your problem about gem/debian and what are you going to do with it specially.

I am using pip and debian now and still no problem by now.